# Is it possible to color the area "outside" of a wpf border rounded corner

Tags: c#, wpf, border

I have the following xaml code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="1 1 0 0" BorderBrush="#25A0DA" CornerRadius="2 0 0 0" Background="Gray">
                            <Label Foreground="White">
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="0" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                            </Label>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Gray" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

                        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1 0 0 1" BorderBrush="#25A0DA" CornerRadius="0 0 0 70" Background="Green"/>

                        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1 0 0 0" BorderBrush="#25A0DA">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="4" />
                        </Border>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Foreground="White" Header="This is some header" Content="This is some content"/>
```

As you can see, my header consists of two borders and a rectangle.

I currently use the rectangle to color the space that the rounded corner of the second border leaves blank.

The space that is currently green should actually be completely transparent however, if I set the background color of the second border to transparent the rest of the rectangle I use to fill the other space becomes visible of course.

How can I make the green part completely transparent (like the content area for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a funny thing called [Path geometry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/geometry-overview). So instead of making the custom header using a combination of `Retangles` and `Borders` with round corners, you can draw more complex shapes easily, with some basic knowledge on Geometry.

So replace them with the following code

**Edit**：Some explanation on the code, the figure is compose of four segments, three of them are line segments, which you just define the end point of the line. And the interesting and more complex one is the `ArcSegment`, which you also need to define the size and direction of the arc, besides the end point of the arc segment. Play with the value of ArcSegment's Size, and see how it changes your shape.

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Gray">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="0, 0">
                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                        <LineSegment Point="100, 0" />
                        <ArcSegment
                            Size="50,50"                                                                  
                            SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"
                            Point="150,50" />   
                        <LineSegment Point="0, 50" />
                        <LineSegment Point="0, 0" />
                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

And you have an outcome like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Path Fill="Red" Data="M10 10 C15 20 30 20 30 20 H10"/>
```

Is this what you want ?